# Solution root could not be located using application root - WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, .net-5

I am trying to get some tests to properly run in CI using the WebApplicationFactory

These tests pass locally when we run them through the IDE but they fail with

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Solution root could not be located using application root
```

When we run them in CI.

In CI, we have a directory called `integration_tests` which contains multiple `dll` files for the tests and we run a `vstest` command to test these dlls, but we do not have the `.sln` file there.

Our WebApplicationFactory goes something like this:

```
factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>()
                .WithWebHostBuilder(b =>
                {
                    b.ConfigureTestServices(s => {});
                });
client = factory.CreateDefaultClient();
```

I have tried using the `WebApplicationFactoryContentRoot` and placing it inside the `AssemblyInfo.cs` but I am unsure that we are using it the right way and I can not find any examples on the docs that actually use it with existing Integration tests.

I have also tried setting the `b.UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot()` for the WebHostBuilder, but again, works only locally.

How can we properly use the `WebApplicationFactoryContentRoot` to allow the `WebApplicationFactory` to not only work locally but also in CI for the published dlls?

Answer (score 2):

`WebApplicationFactory` ignores custom content root path set in `WithWebHostBuilder`, so `UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot` and `UseContentRoot` won't work.

There are a few ways you could set the content root for test server:

1. Use the [`WebApplicationFactoryContentRootAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#how-the-test-infrastructure-infers-the-app-content-root-path)

> on the assembly containing the integration tests with a key equal to the `TEntryPoint` assembly `System.Reflection.Assembly.FullName`

and you need to make sure the marker file exists in the directory.

For example, the code below sets content root to `AppContext.BaseDirectory`:

```
// In your test assembly:
[assembly: WebApplicationFactoryContentRoot(
    key: "WebApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    contentRootPath: "",
    contentRootTest: "WebApplication1.dll",
    priority: "-1000")]
```

2. Copy `sln` file to directory.
3. Set `ASPNETCORE_TEST_CONTENTROOT_APPNAME` as per the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ed26f13cee4caa7aae1649aa48710854f947dc47/src/Mvc/Mvc.Testing/src/WebApplicationFactory.cs#L283).